# OpenStack Juno (Devstack) - How to Specify New Neutron Plugin Configuration Files?

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-neutron, openstack-juno

I wasn't certain whether to put this question on stackoverflow or serverfault, but I think it is more coding related than IT infrastructure related.

I'm adding a new Neutron L3 plugin and have attempted to mimic the functionality of a few good examples thus far. My problem is here: while my config file is following the same naming conventions/locations, I keep having empty strings returned from Oslo Config.

Edit: my plugin `myapp` is in `/opt/stack/neutron/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/myapp` and my configuration file `ml2_conf_myapp.ini` is in `/opt/stack/neutron/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/`.

How do you specify to Oslo config where to find new plugin configuration files and what their names are?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by reading through the code in devstack/lib/neutron.

In devstack/local.conf, you can set the variables `Q_PLUGIN_EXTRA_CONF_FILES` and `Q_PLUGIN_EXTRA_CONF_PATH`.

In my case, I have:

```
ML2_L3_PLUGIN=neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.myapp.myapp
Q_PLUGIN_EXTRA_CONF_FILES+="myapp_conf.ini"
Q_PLUGIN_EXTRA_CONF_PATH="$DEST/neutron/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/myapp"
```

Now Oslo is able to pick up the configurations.

I hope this helps someone else save some work.